# how can I change the startSeconds of Youtube dynamically in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, youtubeplayer

what I expected is that whenever the startSeconds property of youtube-player changes, the youtube-player would jump to the new startSeconds.
However, although I had changed the variable bound to startSeconds property,
the youtube video didn't play from the startSeconds I just set.

may I know if it is viable viable way or there is another method to reach what I anticipated?

Thanks

```
 <youtube-player 
  [videoId]="videoId" 
  suggestedQuality="highres" 
  [height]="250" 
  [width]="500" 
  [startSeconds]="timeStamp">
</youtube-player>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`startSeconds` is an `@Input`](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/main/src/youtube-player/youtube-player.ts#L147) so you should be able to bind to it.

```html
<youtube-player [startSeconds]="30"></youtube-player>
```

However, while the [latest value from the binding is used](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/1c7b9403f130d40cc28a79adb4f3887f0e8aaff6/src/youtube-player/youtube-player.ts#L723), it's only considered if the player has been created and hasn't started playing.

```js
const cueOptionsObs = combineLatest([startSecondsObs, endSecondsObs]).pipe(
  map(([startSeconds, endSeconds]) => ({startSeconds, endSeconds})),
);

// Only respond to changes in cue options if the player is not running.
const filteredCueOptions = cueOptionsObs.pipe(
  filterOnOther(playerObs, player => !!player && !hasPlayerStarted(player)),
);
```

The player is considered to have started playing [if it's in any state except `UNSTARTED` or `CUED`](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/1c7b9403f130d40cc28a79adb4f3887f0e8aaff6/src/youtube-player/youtube-player.ts#L767).

```js
function hasPlayerStarted(player: YT.Player): boolean {
  const state = player.getPlayerState();
  return state !== YT.PlayerState.UNSTARTED && state !== YT.PlayerState.CUED;
}
```

So you cannot change the binding of `startSeconds` to make the player jump. You might be able to change the `playbackState` to `CUED` by [calling `stopVideo()`](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/1c7b9403f130d40cc28a79adb4f3887f0e8aaff6/src/youtube-player/youtube-player.ts#L344), after which you should be able to change the value of `startSeconds` before calling `startVideo()` to start at your new position.

```js
stopVideo() {
  if (this._player) {
    this._player.stopVideo();
  } else {
    // It seems like YouTube sets the player to CUED when it's stopped.
    this._getPendingState().playbackState = YT.PlayerState.CUED
  }
}
```